# Combining an animation of an UIImageView with a transition

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, core-animation

I am doing a transition of an UIImageView's image and would also like to move the image view at the same time. The results so far is that the image transitions, but not while moving.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 2.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "otherImage")
        }, completion: nil)

        imageViewTopConstraint.constant = 200

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, the image does dissolve and move, but I want the dissolve effect to happen while the imageView is moving. It now dissolves in it's initial position and once the transition is done you see the image move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your imageView inside a container, then animate the constraints of the container while doing the transition on the imageView.

Comment: Ooooh, that sounds promising. — Yup, tried it. Excellent.

Comment: Yeah, this works and I can keep the amount of outlets to 2. Thanks.